# Cannot tranfer() ETH to Gnosis Safe

Tags: out-of-gas, gnosis-safe, address.transfer

I'm praying to the blockchain gods that somebody answers us.
 
I'm with a NFT collection. We ran our pre-sale the last 2 days and collected 56.925 ETH.

The smart contract address with the withdraw method being called is:

[https://etherscan.io/tx/0x8d079d4db5ee36ac9eb6c248904986e2e3669c0df743be2abe7df77a06d267b8](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x8d079d4db5ee36ac9eb6c248904986e2e3669c0df743be2abe7df77a06d267b8%C2%A0)

If you look under Internal Txns:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x8d079d4db5ee36ac9eb6c248904986e2e3669c0df743be2abe7df77a06d267b8#internal

https://etherscan.io/address/0x915fd7751dbbd3d4e8b359d5b99486941636c12f#internaltx

You will see that many different wallet addresses are getting called to do the transfers
You will see that the specific wallet is a contract address and it's using Gnosis MultiSig. https://etherscan.io/address/0x915fd7751dbbd3d4e8b359d5b99486941636c12f

Note: The account holder already has made sure they have upgraded to the latest version. 
Whenever our withdraw method from our Magic Mind smart contract hits this Gnosis MultiSig contract wallet.

We have a smart contract that has a withdrawal function that has many different wallet addresses that we send payments to.
We attempted to call our withdraw function and one of the wallet addresses is a Gnosis MultiSig....
Every time our .transfer method attempts to send payment to this wallet we keep getting 
Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Out of gas]

https://etherscan.io/address/0x915fd7751dbbd3d4e8b359d5b99486941636c12f#internaltx

The result of this is our entire withdrawal method is failing and we are unable to get the funds out of our smart contract.

We are desperately in need of assistance.

In addition we are setup to go live on our public sale at 1 PM Pacific / 4 PM Eastern time USA ... That is in +5 hours from now.

Comment: since your sending to GnosisSafe, with transfer method there is not enough gas to execute the transaction 
`transfer` (2300 gas, throws error)
`send` (2300 gas, returns bool)
`call` (forward all gas or set gas, returns bool)

Edit: Exactly what Daniel Sanchez shared,+ unfortunately you hardcoded all the value

Answer (score 6):

This is explanied here:

- https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/5249851-why-can-t-i-transfer-eth-from-a-contract-into-a-safe

You can also check further information in this post

- https://consensys.net/diligence/blog/2019/09/stop-using-soliditys-transfer-now/

Hope this can help. If you carefully check each internal call you can see all of them are limited to 2300 gas limit

Answer (score 1):

We successfully resolved this issue by utilizing the example snippet from the repository:

https://github.com/folia-app/eip-2929

In summary:

We needed to load our contracts ABI into ethers library and then pass a override object utilizing a custom `accessList` array.

Thank you!

Comment: wish this worked for BSC as well sigh